# Te-form beginner question

Tags: grammar, verbs, て-form

> いもうとは東京に行っています。

How can I discover the meaning of this sentence? I'm studying the te-form and I'm a little bit confused. The correct translation will be:

> My little sister is in Tokyo (she´s already there)

or

> My little sister is going to Tokyo (progressive action) ?

Or I see by the context? This verb form is SO damnnn cruel to learn ;___;

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it can mean both.

Comment: I'd say 妹は東京に向かっています rather than 東京に行っています for the second one.

Comment: @Chris I believe you're mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

I would simply say いもうとは東京にいます for "My little sister is in Tokyo."

いもうとは東京に行っています has the connotation that she is *away* in Tokyo, hence she is not here.

I would say いもうとは東京に行くところです (or  いもうとは東京に向け移動中です if you prefer a more formal style) for "My little sister is going to Tokyo."

*** added ***
I think @Choko's choice 妹は東京に向かっています works as well.